# convert image to byte[] and to base64 string

Tags: c#, winforms

i wanna convert the image in the picture box to `base64 String`.

```
private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmaccount.pbID.Image = (Bitmap)pbCapture.Image.Clone();//this is the image i wanna Convert to base64
        device.Stop();
        this.Dispose();
    }
```

PS. the image is taken from my camera and i want to save it as `base64 String`.

Comment: what type is it? what methods does it have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your image to a `byte[]` first

```
ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
var bytes = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo((Bitmap)pbCapture.Image, typeof(byte[]));
```

and then to a base64 `string`

```
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
```